# How to use CypherDslRepository and CypherDSL to query Neo4J db

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I am new to Neo4J and so far have been using annotated queries to query graph database using Neo4j-spring. I have read that CypherDslRepository and CypherDSL can be used to query Neo4j db, but could not come across a satisfactory example.

Could someone please explain and provide an example of how to use this ?
Thanks.

Comment: thanks for asking this question.. my question is sort of similar http://stackoverflow.com/q/22989614/1660192

Answer (score 1):

That's fairly well documented at http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/2.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/programming-model.html#d0e2887