# Cypher query vs cypher dsl in spring data neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, dynamicquery

I want to know about neo4j dsl recommendation in Spring data neo4j framework.
As of now I used to create repository interface extending from `GraphRepository`,`NamedIndexRepository` etc. and write my custom methods with my custom cypher query with `@Query` annotation as below:

```
@Query(value="START root=node:__types__(className='com.data.EntityNode') WHERE root.id={0} and "
        + "root.type={1} return root")  
T findByIdAndType(String id, String type);
```

above method works nicely as far as I consider the static query. but right now I am in need to use some other way where I can generate cypher query depending upon my need !. then I came across **neo4j dsl** library which looks like a solution to my requirement.
ref: [link-1](http://rickardoberg.wordpress.com/2011/11/14/creating-a-dsl-for-cypher-graph-queries/)  [link-2](https://github.com/neo4j/cypher-dsl)

My question is:

1. is it OK to use `neo4j dsl` lib in Spring data neo4j (I am using v2.1.0 RELEASE) ? or
2. is there any other way to generate dynamic cypher query in spring data neo4j for given set of situation ?  and more interesting
3. is it possible to generate query from cypher dsl and pass it to my custom repository interface, execute them and get result (I mean `@Query` value)? because if yes then I dont have to add major changes to my existing design.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Update to 3.0.1.RELEASE
2. It is ok to use cypher DSL
3. As annotations are compile time and Cypher DSL is runtime you cannot use them there, but
4. you can inherit from CypherDSLRepository which adds some nice methods to your repository

Comment: oh thats nice, I just got this link as well http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/2.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/programming-model.html#d0e2887 right now I am not able to upgrade my Spring data neo4j version to 3.0.1 I guess it require Spring version 3.2.5 ..

Comment: is the preference changed over period of time now? I find official spring-data neo4j reference [recommends to avoid cypher-dsl](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#_built_in_query_dsl_support).

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but some feedback:

The Cypher-DSl https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/cypher-dsl has been rebooted last year and is now an integral part of Spring Data Neo4j 6.

Our new docs spot an example: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/6.0.5/reference/html/#faq.custom-queries-and-custom-mappings All statements build from the DSL can be passed to the Neo4j Template.

I hope someone finds this useful.